# Display item over multiple columns with Grid

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid

So basically I have a slider and I want the slider to "go into multiple columns". I have 7 columns (because of 7 different labels that I wanted to locate), and I want my slider to go in front of all 7 of those columns.

I have added a [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxQCo.jpg) to make things clearer (I hope it makes things clearer :p): You can see that the slider only goes to the end of the 1st column, I want it to go to the end of the 7th column

Everything that's green is notes.
I have numbered the columns and added how I want the slider to be located.

I tried assigning multiple columns to the slider (apparently that's not possible)

UPDATE: added the picture

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code written?

Comment: Take a look a `ColumnSpan`

Comment: @Andersnk, Would you like to see my .XAML code?

Comment: @shanranm Where could I see that? In the toolbox I can't find anything of that

Comment: Ohh nevermind @shanranm! That helped me out a lot! Thank you! This solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved it for me:

```
Grid.ColumnSpan="7"
```